# What are the major steps to consider while doing competitive analysis?

Tags: lean-ux

What is a correct way to start of with the competitive analysis process and how to evaluate? I am new to this field, haven't done it before. What all the factors i should focus on the most? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can see several ways to interpret this question. I'll answer both.

**If your UX position is in management**, you might conduct a S.W.O.T. analysis—a common form of comparative analysis. SWOT means Strengths-Weaknesses-Opportunities-Threats. You assess your company's Strengths and Opportunities in terms of your product, and you assess your Weaknesses and Threats in terms of other companies and their products.

**If your UX position is tactical**, then you may have been asked to review other products in the same product space (direct competitors) or in a different product space. You start by doing an inventory. Who has what? This often results in a me-too product strategy, and is not typically very user-centred. That's because it often results in feature-itis, a bewildering array of features that users don't need, but that Marketing sees as essential to sell the product.

If you do a more in-depth assessment, for example by measuring user performance in competing products, then that can help set a baseline or target to beat.

An analysis of products in a different space is usually intended to find insight for innovation. Can an idea from a different product that solves a different problem be re-purposes in your product.

—

How you conduct your competitor analysis depends on what you need to accomplish.